# Why is the CSS Sticky property wiping out other elements as it passes

Tags: html, css, sticky

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to make it so a list forms on the page while the user scrolls.
Everything functions as expected right up until the last element in which is "wipes out" all the other elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #15192c;
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.list {
  margin: 10em 5em;
  font-size: 200%;
}

aside {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 500%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

.aside h1 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 500%;
}

article {
  flex: 2;
  height: 120%;
}

#developer {
  position: sticky;
  top: 4em;
}

#designer {
  position: sticky;
  top: 6em;
}

#student {
  position: sticky;
  top: 8em;
}

#learner {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10em;
}

#entrepreneur {
  position: sticky;
  top: 12em;
}

#programmer {
  position: sticky;
  top: 14em;
}

#champion {
  position: sticky;
  top: 16em;
}

#risk-taker {
  position: sticky;
  top: 18em;
}

#mistake-maker {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <aside>
    <h1>Hello.</h1>
    <p>I'm a</p>
  </aside>
  <article>
    <section class="list" id="developer">
      <h2>Developer</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="list" id="designer">
      <h2>Designer</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="list" id="student">
      <h2>Student</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="list" id="learner">
      <h2>Learner</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="list" id="entrepreneur">
      <h2>Entrepreneur</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="list" id="programmer">
      <h2>Programmer</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="list" id="champion">
      <h2>Champion</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="list" id="risk-taker">
      <h2>Risk-Taker</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="list" id="mistake-maker">
      <h2>Mistake-Maker</h2>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

Here it is on CodePen: https://codepen.io/jason43/pen/oNvJWYQ

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), something that's `position: sticky` stays stuck "...until meeting the opposite edge of its containing block," which is to say that it unsticks once you scroll past it, which makes sense, otherwise there'd be no way to get to content farther down the page (or else that content would overlap stuck content). How you go about fixing that is probably fairly complicated, so I'm not going to attempt an answer, but at least now you know why.

Comment: My *guess* is that you would need a JavaScript solution to really do this nicely where, once the final list item drops in place, the entire section scrolls away as one big group. But again, that may be kind of out of scope of this question since you haven't really attempted a solution like that so far.

Answer (score -1):

change the position values to fix; that is

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

this should work